# Frontend cannot link Access tables to Azure SQL Database tables

Tags: ms-access, azure-sql-database, database-migration

I've used Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access (SSMA) to migrate an Access database to an Azure SQL database. I use sql server authentication and the tables are linked and the credential password is stored for each table. Everything looks fine, when I open the Access database file. allt the tables have a blue arrow-globe icon to show they are linked to Azure. I can browse the tables and see the data.
But when I open the frontend Access file which points to the Access database file and relink the tables there - it gives an error for all the tables and just displays: failed. Where can I see more details about the error?

Comment: You need to point the FE file directly to the linked tables, not another access database?

Comment: yes, I also realized that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pointing directly to the frontend Access file solved the problem.